# for Loop only check the last value in the vector to check duplicates in SQL Server with R?

Tags: sql, r, loops, shiny

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
myDatabase <- 'MyDB'
myDriver <- 'SQL Server'
myServer <- 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS'

con <- pool::dbPool(odbc::odbc(), Driver = myDriver,
                    Server = myServer,
                    Database = myDatabase,
                    Trusted_Connection = 'True')

Caddy_id <- c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10")

for(i in 1:length(Caddy_id)){
  
check_duplicate <- dbGetQuery(con,paste0("DECLARE @container AS INT = 0
                                            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.P1000_Packing WITH(NOLOCK)
                                              WHERE Caddy_1 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_2 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_3 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_4 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_5 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_6 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_7 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_8 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_9 = '",Caddy_id[i],"' OR
                                                    Caddy_10 = '",Caddy_id[i],"')
                                              BEGIN
                                                   SET @container = 1
                                              END
                                            SELECT @container;"))

}
check_duplicate
```

I want to check all values for duplicates in SQL Server with R, but only the last value in the vector *Caddy_id* can be checked.

Why does only the value 10 return *1* and another values will return *0* even if they exist in the sql table?

This table returns 1

[image].

but this table returns 0

[image]

If I change the vector `Caddy_id <- c("C0","C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9")`
it also returns 1

Comment: It's because you're replacing the value of the `check_duplicate` variable every time through the loop, so when the loop exits, it only corresponds to the last value of `Caddy_id[I]`, which is `C10`. One option would be have another variable called (say) `result`, set it to 0 before the loop, and set it to 1 if `check_duplicate` is 1 inside the loop.  There are other options (like using SQL `in`, or reading in your table and looking for the vector variables in R instead), but that looks like the least change to your code

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your query runs by itself in each iteration where `@container` is reset each time back to zero. Therefore, only the very last running count is retained and `check_duplicate` is replaced each time.

However, consider counting duplicates in R by building a list of aggregated count vectors for each caddy id. Be sure to also run queries safely with parameters where one approach includes [**`sqlInterpolate`**](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#interpolation-by-hand).

```r
Caddy_id <- c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10")

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count]
       FROM dbo.P1000_Packing
       WHERE Caddy_1  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_2  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_3  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_4  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_5  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_6  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_7  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_8  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_9  = ?cad_id OR
             Caddy_10 = ?cad_id"

check_duplicates <- sapply(
    Caddy_id, 
    function(i) {
        qry <- sqlInterpolate(con, sql, ?cad_id = i)
        dbGetQuery(con, qry)$count
    }
)

total_duplicates <- sum(check_duplicates, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

An alternative SQL query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM dbo.P1000_Packing
WHERE ?cad_id IN (
     Caddy_1, Caddy_2, Caddy_3, Caddy_4, Caddy_5,
     Caddy_6, Caddy_7, Caddy_8, Caddy_9, Caddy_10
)
```